# How to prevent dupilcate value at table creation

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose user name and phone number should be unique  at the time of table define without using unique constraint and check constraint in sql server.i don't want to create sp for that.please suggest any otherway to prevent duplicate column in sql server r2 2008. Il

Comment: Why without `unique constraint`

Comment: Create trigger. But what's wrong with UNIQUE?

Comment: You have check existence of `user name` and `phone number` combination every time you insert

Comment: Mr.pradip.as per my knowledge it take more time for execution.

Answer (score 1):

One correct way (and really the best way) is to use a unique constraint.  It is unclear whether you want one or two constraints, based on your description.  If you don't want a unique constraint, you should explain why not.

That is, if you want the pair to be unique:

```
 alter table add constraint unq_t_username_phonenumber unique (username, phonenumber);
```

Or you want each one to be unique:

```
 alter table add constraint unq_t_username unique (username);
 alter table add constraint unq_t_phonenumber unique (phonenumber);
```

When you define the table, you can also do one-column unique constraints in-line:

```
create table . . . (
    . . .,
    UserName varchar(255) not null unique,
    . . .
);
```

Almost equivalent to a unique constraint is a unique index:

```
create unique index unq_t_username on t(username);
```

The difference is that you can name the constraint.  This name is handy when a violation occurs, because the constraint name (but not index name) is typically in the message.